# is this exactly what romfs in Linux kernel does?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I have to create a file system with customized loadable modules with romfs. However, I have a few confusions (I'm still new to the kernel stuffs):

- After reading `romfs` document: [romfs](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.6/Documentation/filesystems/romfs.txt), as far as I know, `romfs` is a filesystem similar to `ext2, ext3, ext4....`, which is used to create init ramdisk required at boot time by the kernel. However, it is said that `romfs` is incorporated into the kernel since version 2.1.21: [romfs homepage](http://romfs.sourceforge.net/). On the homepage, we can only download the `genromfs` utility, which is used to create `romfs` image file. So, I want to be clear here: the module `romfs` included in the kernel is for reading `romfs` filesystem, and `genromfs` is used to create one, isn't it (I tried `genromfs`, but I want to be confirmed)?
- `initrd` is created by `mkinitrd -allow-missing -f initrd.img kernel-version` at a source directory (the filesystem to be loaded) and unpackaged by: `gzip -dc initrd.img | cpio -idv`, while using romfs, I have to create its image by using `mkinitrd` and unpackage it using: `genromfs -fdv romfs.img`. Is this the same as initrd at kernel boot time? `initrd` involves compressing, while `romfs` is not, is this ok?
- If so, the `romfs` module has to be built into the kernel for reading at early kernel boot phase, is that right? In my system, we have a diskless machine, and currently, `initrd` is used as a boot phase filesystem as well as final root filesystem. However, since `romfs` is meant for read only, is using `romfs` denied users the ability to write into filesystem (so, we can't do thing like `echo "something" > /tmp/something.txt`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), yes, the module `romfs` is the file system that supports a simple read-only file system that is very simple in implementation. The program `genroms` allows you to create an instance of a romfs file system that can be mounted and accessed under a kernel that has the `romfs` module loaded.

The genromfs tool generates a file system image that can be placed on a block device, or onto a file on a pre-existing file system.

For (2), you can use a `romfs` file system as an initial ram disk - as long as there is compiled-in kernel support for accessing a `romfs` file system. The difference comes at initrd load time. For a standard `initrd` image, it gets decompressed into the ramdisk that is used to initiate boot, with a romfs image, it is not uncompressed, it is simply used as-is.

The primary reason for using a `romfs` image as a file system is that it could be placed onto a block of read-only memory, and accessed directly in that manner without needing to use physical memory for the expanded ramdisk image.

For (3), yes, you must compile the file system into the system as a built-in component, rather than a loadable module - i.e. you choose '`Y`' for the `rom file system` option in the kernel file system configuration.

I would not recommend using a romfs file system as a root file system - there are insufficient POSIX attributes (ownership, permissions) to allow it to run as a proper file system for general day-to-day use (I don't know for certain; I just would find using a file system like this very *strange*)

An initrd is decompressed *into memory* at run-time, so any writing to the file system is not persisted after a reboot of the system. If the file system on that expanded ramdisk has the appropriate permissions, then the kernel should prevent changes being made by ordinary users to specific content on the disk. You would not allow the user to log onto the system as root, and rely on the permissions of the file system from preventing modifications to the files.

The fact that it is read-only and unmodifiable means that if you wanted to have a /tmp file, then you would need to have created the directory as part of the `genromfs` call, and then you would have to mount tmpfs onto that mount point in order to perform a write into that directory.

If you're looking for a way of having a root file system that is read-only, then you should consider mounting a read-only share from a remote file system; that way there is no actual way for the user to make modifications to the file system - all write efforts would be rejected by the server. By using a feature like [`FS-Cache/CacheFS`](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7378/), the performance would be quite good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Our system contains diskless computers, which loads the kernel `vmlinuz` and `initrd` via tftp. Therefore, the only and final filesystem the diskless computers have is `initrd`, which is used at boot and after boot (the computers are  used only for processing and nothing else).

Comment: I have been confirmed that we are going to used the `romfs` filesystem for extension purpose. Usually, in order to enable support a new module, we have to recompile the kernel. Thus, the `romfs` image is used to contain additional modules we want to add to the system, and if we want to add new modules, we only have to compile the `romfs` image, and the modules are managed in here.

Comment: In other words, it will be used in the same manner as any other initrd - to add drivers that support other types of hardware

Answer (score 2):

The `romfs` filesystem has basically fallen out of use today, as it is very limited. You would only use it if you had a large read-only medium and no interest in compression.

It used to be that the initrd was a `romfs` image that was mounted from the RAM block where it was loaded, and after unmount, the RAM block was freed; this has been replaced by a `tmpfs` instance (read/write RAM based filesystem) that is initialized with data from a `cpio` format archive (similar to a ZIP file).

There is a point in the boot process where the kernel unloads all code that will never be needed again ("Freeing init memory"), this happens right before process 1 is started. With the `romfs` approach, the initrd is mounted from the initrd image at this point, so the code required for accessing the romfs image as well as the initrd code must remain loaded here, which means that you end up with some dead kernel code after the system is booted.

The current initrd approach uses the same ramdisk code that is also used later for the `/tmp` filesystem (if your system is configured this way), and the entire initialization of that filesystem is run before the point where the memory is freed, so no dead code remains loaded after the initrd is booted.

Neither romfs nor cpio format initrds can be written to; the new code path copies the data to a writeable filesystem first, which allows your initrd scripts to write data; however this is never written back into the image.

Comment: So, `romfs` and `initrd` are used for loading kernel modules, and afterward, if the system has an external storage (hard drive), then it will be discarded and replaced with the actual filesystem, am I correct?

Comment: `initrd` is the mechanism for loading a block of data along with the kernel, this data block used to be mounted via the `romfs` filesystem in earlier versions. These days, the initrd contains a cpio archive (built using `mkinitrd`) that is unpacked into the `initramfs` before the initrd is discarded.